# Clear contents of hidden excel cells based on dropdown menu vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to clear a set of cells (reset them) every time a new option is selected in the dropdown menu. However, based on the choice selected, a different combination of rows will be hidden. There are 12 of these dropdowns and so I need a function I can call that will clear only the cells related to that drop down (when all are unhidden there are 16 rows and 3 columns). I have tried using the formula below, however it does not recognize the hidden rows and ends up deleting the contents of the following dropdown's rows. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
 Sub Clear(Target As Range)
      Range(Target.Offset(16,).Address, Target.Offset(,3).Address).Value = " "
 End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to clear it, it should be `.Value = ""` (Nothing between the quotes). The way you have it would fill each cell with one whitespace character.

Comment: Also, offset does not skip hidden cells, so the problem lies elsewhere. Have you tried making the 12 ranges into named ranges? That may make your life easier when writing the code. You could simply write `If MyDropdown = "Name1" Then NamedRange1.ClearContents` with ElseIf x11 for the other ranges

Comment: You could even put all the dropdown options and associated namedranges into a dictionary and do `OptionDictionary(MyDropDown.Value).ClearContents` No need for If/Else, just a single line.